# How do I mass extract string resources from an Array in Android Studio?

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-studio

I have a few String arrays with about 50 different strings in each. I would like to do "extract string resources" in bulk or at least as fast as possible so that these would be translatable. How would I go about doing this seeing as I don't even have the "extract string resources" option for arrays in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way of doing this was making a stringbuilder. Then making my own for loop which went over each item in the array and created a string resource for it by appending the necessary things. When it was done I printed the whole thing to my log and then just had to copy and paste it. One could use this method for creating the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can search all hardcoded String first Go to "Analyze > Run Inspection By Name.", and type "Hardcoded text". Run that one against your whole project, and you should get an inspection results panel that will show the hardcoded text instances.

You can also go to Android Studio > Preferences > Inspections > Hardcoded text and specify exactly how it runs, and what (if any) special cases are excluded from inspection.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I assume it is due to strings being hardcoded in an array. Is it supposed to make a difference? If so is there any way to mass fix this or do I have to do it by hand? Thanks in advance!